# Output difference between two float values as daily difference sum from a MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I have the following content in a MariaDB table:
[image]

The structure of the table is as follows:
[image]

There can be several "intermediate values" per day, so that I can use the following SQL command:

```
SELECT
  MAX(PayLoad_REAL) - MIN(PayLoad_REAL) AS PayLoad_REAL_Difference
FROM
  TEST_STATUS
WHERE
  Topic = 'test'
  AND DATE_TIME BETWEEN '2023-12-11' AND '2023-12-12';
```

Get the difference from 2023-12-11 to 2023-12-12 filtered.
In this case 20.5 - 10 = 10.5
But I get 7 back as the result.

It is an energy meter that sends values to the database several times a day. I would like to use the query to find out how high the daily difference is. In the example above, the last reading on 11.12.23 is 10 and the reading on 12.12.23 is 20.5 This results in a delta of 10.5 over the day

What do I have to change/what am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your query will return 20.5 - 3 = 17.5 not 7 why do you think it should return 10.5 ?

Comment: The query (as is) will return 7  (= 10 - 3). The last row doesn't match the BETWEEN condition.

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve. We cannot guess it from a non-working code.

Comment: It is an energy meter that sends values to the database several times a day.
I would like to use the query to find out how high the daily difference is.
In the example above, the last reading on 11.12.23 is 10 and the reading on 12.12.23 is 20.5
This results in a delta of 10.5 over the day.
I hope this makes it clear what the task is :)

Comment: "[..] query to find out how high the daily difference is" - That should be written in your question. And you should also clearly and unambiguously define the "daily difference". Otherwise you will get answers, that try to fix something in your query, which is not even close to what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question. Do you know what the SQL query command should look like?

Comment: *And you should also clearly and unambiguously define the "daily difference".*  - I still have no idea how you choose the two rows to compare. Why is it not `20.5 - 3`? All I can guess, is that you compare max value from one day with max value from another day. But that info is nowhere to find in your question.

Comment: `FLOAT` (if whole dollars/Euros) tops out at 16,777,215 or (if dollars and cents) 167,772.15.  Consider using `INT` or `DECIMAL(nn,2)`

Comment: The short answer is that `.. AND '2023-12-12'` is equivalent to `... AND '2023-12-12' 00:00:00`, thereby excluding the last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found a way of calculating the daily difference which on the one hand calculates the difference and on the other queries the highest daily value:

```
SELECT
  DATEDIFF('2023-12-12', '2023-12-11') * (
    COALESCE((SELECT MAX(PayLoad_REAL) FROM TEST_STATUS WHERE DATE_TIME = '2023-12-12'), 0) -
    COALESCE((SELECT MAX(PayLoad_REAL) FROM TEST_STATUS WHERE DATE_TIME = '2023-12-11'), 0)
  ) AS day_difference;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DATE_TIME` field is defined as `timestamp` and your `WHERE` clause gets dates between 2023-12-11 and 2023-12-12.

Out of the rows in the image, the first three will qualify as the timestamp value for the last row is greater than 2023-12-12.

The maximum `PayLoad_REAL` for the rows is 10 and the minimum is 3. Difference of those is 7.

If you want to compare only with date part, cast the timestamp to a date:

```
AND CAST(DATE_TIME as date) BETWEEN '2023-12-11' AND '2023-12-12';
```

and if you want to get the data from just one day:

```
AND CAST(DATE_TIME as date) = '2023-12-11';
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the explanation.

However, I get the SQL Query. 

the result: 17.5

To explain how the values are obtained: It is an energy meter that sends values to the database several times a day.
I want to use the query to find out how high the daily difference is.
In the example above, the last reading on 11.12.23 is 10 and the reading on 12.12.23 is 20.5
This results in a delta of 10.5 over the day. I would have liked to select this difference.
I hope this makes it clear what the task is :)

Comment: if you want to get data just from one day (your query does it for two days), you can use `AND CAST(DATE_TIME as date) = '2023-12-11'`.

Comment: @slaakso -  Both suggestions are not [_sargable_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) .  Furthermore, the first suggestion includes an extra midnight.

Comment: @RickJames  The first example was for condition on *two* days, so there is no extra midnight. And yes, using `CAST` denies the use of index. The answer was to make point about the date handling.